R8 removes entire classes it shouldn't
After migrating Gradle from 8.4 to 8.9 and Gradle plugin from 8.3.2 to 8.7.0, R8 is failing when building a signed release APK.
Missing class com.my.package.MyClass$Companion (referenced from: void common.my.package.workers.SyncWorker.<init>(android.content.Context, androidx.work.WorkerParameters, com.my.package.Dao))

It fails with many more missing classes. I did add -keep class com.my.package.** { *; } to the app module (in proguard-rules.txt) and to my other modules (in consumer-rules.txt) but to no avails. I also added android.enableR8.fullMode=false to my gradle.properties but it didn't change anything. Android Studio do generates missing-rules.txt with a bunch of -dontwarn which make the build pass but the app crashes right away with the same missing classes error.
Any Idea of how I can fix this? I see the documentation saying

I have the same issue. Also, tried with adding "...fullMode=false", and it didn't work. Did you find any solution for it?

I was able to resolve the issue in my case, and you might have the same issue.
You indirectly mentioned that you have multiple modules. Do you by any chance set the minify flag to true for them, for the library modules?
This was the case with me, and that was the problem.
I was able to better isolate the issue, it wasn't about upgrading the Gradle version to "8.9", rather, it was about upgrading the AGP to "8.4.0" and higher (which can also be valid for you since you had started with "8.3.2").
The problem is explained here:
https://developer.android.com/build/releases/past-releases/agp-8-4-0-release-notes#library-classes-shrunk
Based on how I understand it with my limited understanding of it, it seems like starting with that version of AGP, when the minify is set to true, it will try to minify the lib module much sooner in the process, as opposed to doing it at the very end. In a way, the app module will have to use a minified version of the lib modules.
Setting "isMinifyEnabled" to false for my library modules, and keeping it to true for my app module did resolve the issue for me. There was even no need to disable full mode for R8.
I think that setting the flags like this is safe, as it is explained for example here (the whole problem is also explained here):
https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/1e8ke67/agp_84_and_hilt_android_library_modules_in/
or here:
https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/xubcff/when_using_proguard_do_i_have_to_set/
Sorry in advance, if this is not the case with you.

Yes that was the same issue! I solved it a few days after by going through our modules and setting the minify flag to false except for the app module.

There is a difference between compile time errors and runtime errors.
The compile time errors that you see are caused by references in the input to classes which are not part of the input. This could be due to missing dependencies or libraries which where not designed to be Android only, and have references to classes only found in OpenJDK. These compile time errors are silenced with the -dontwarn directives.
The runtime errors are missing classes at runtime, typically classes removed by R8. Here additional keep rules are usually the answer.
However, if it is the same missing class, then the class was already missing in the input, and no keep rule can bring it back. If it is not exactly the same classe, you can file an issue on https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=326788 with reference to this question and information on what was otherwise changed when upgrading the Android Gradle plugin from 8.3.2 to 8.7.0.

The missing classes are all classes I created myself, they contain the app logic. And it's the same classes missing at compile time and runtime. The missing-rules files only suggest to add -dontwarn for my own classes, which is weird. I assumed R8 would not try to remove classes used by the app.

If the missing-rules generated are suggesting -dontwarn for classes which are part of the app code, then there must be something wrong with your project setup, as then these classes are somehow not seen as part of the app, as they are not passed to R8 by AGP in the first place.
