Missing classes detected while running R8. Please add the missing classes or apply additional keep rules that are generated, AGP 8.4.0
I'm getting this error after upgrading to AGP 8.4.0, I've been directed to following path:

D:\User\projects\MyApp\app\build\outputs\mapping\release\missing_rules.txt.

I copied the contents into my app-level Proguard, which allowed the project to build successfully, but now I'm facing ClassNotFound exceptions runtime. I also tried adding -dontwarn in each module, but that didn’t resolve the issue.
Android Studio: LadyBug

Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79102013/r8-removes-entire-classes-it-shouldnt, which seems to be a similar issue. The ClassNotFound runtime issue is most likely not related to the missing classes on input.
